# How to enable compression on Django project and still be safe?

Tags: python, django, compression, gzip

We're using Python Django for our project. When I tested the website on google page speed, I saw a warning of `Enable compression`, `Leverage browser caching`, and `Reduce server response time`. For this post I'd like to ask regarding the `Enable compression` problem. I myself has no experience with GZIP compression and my backender has no experience with this as well. One thing is, he suggested not to do it due to a warning on Django site:

> Warning
>
> Security researchers recently revealed that when compression
>   techniques (including GZipMiddleware) are used on a website, the site
>   becomes exposed to a number of possible attacks. These approaches can
>   be used to compromise, among other things, Django’s CSRF protection.
>   Before using GZipMiddleware on your site, you should consider very
>   carefully whether you are subject to these attacks. If you’re in any
>   doubt about whether you’re affected, you should avoid using
>   GZipMiddleware. For more details, see the the BREACH paper (PDF) and
>   breachattack.com.

How do I enable compression and still be safe? What do I need to do?

Comment: The test reduced to the basics says: read the paper, assert if you are subject to the attacks, if you are or you are not sure don't use the compression. You seem to be not sure.

Comment: Our website is not huge or anything but we've been hacked several times.. therefore I am a bit hesitant. However, I'd like to aim highest page speed possible.